# Python: 1) How to reference two string variables and insert a list element in between? 2) How can I append the string constructed to a list?

Tags: python

Here is a .txt file (semi colon signifies start of file):

```
MiddlePhrase.txt:
coke and cheeseburgers
bread and wine
beer and tacos
```

Here is the code I have now:

```
middlePhrases = open('MiddlePhrase.txt', 'r')

firstPhrase = 'I love to drink and eat '
secondPhrase = ' when I am at the beach!'

for i in middlePhrases:
    print(beginningPhrase,{},endPhrase)
```

The goal is to write the first line of 'MiddlePhrase.txt' to a new .txt file named 'NewPhraseFile.txt', then append the following two lines in 'MiddlePhrase.txt' to the 'NewPhraseFile.txt'

This is the desired output (a new .txt file being written with content):

```
NewPhraseFile.txt:
I love to drink and eat coke and cheeseburgers when I am at the beach!
I love to drink and eat bread and wine when I am at the beach!
I love to drink and eat beer and tacos when I am at the beach!
```

Comment: can you show the code you have tried?

Comment: Please edit the post with your attempt at solving the question.

Comment: Okay, give me a minute to edit it! Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried something? Please add your code snippet and tell the problem with your code.

Comment: I have updated the question with more relevant code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short version

```py
open('new.txt', 'a+').writelines(
    f'I love to drink and eat {x.strip()} when I am at the beach!\n'
    for x in open('mid.txt'))
```

Comment: Woah mama! Nice code! *fire emoji*

Answer (score 1):

I hope this works for you...

```py
firstPhrase = 'I love to drink and eat '
secondPhrase = ' when I am at the beach!'
with open('MiddlePhrase.txt', 'r') as middlePhrases, open('NewPhraseFile.txt', 'a') as newPhrases:
    for phrase in middlePhrases:
        middlePhrase = phrase.strip()
        newPhrases.write(firstPhrase + middlePhrase + secondPhrase + '\n')
```

Output in NewPhraseFile.txt:

```
I love to drink and eat coke and cheeseburger when I am at the beach!
I love to drink and eat bread and wine when I am at the beach!
I love to drink and eat beer and tacos when I am at the beach!
```

Comment: Awesome code! Thank you. Happy holidays!

Comment: you don't need to close the file `new` as `with` will automatically handle that for you. you need to close `fp` though, as you are not using `with` there.